# Training c3d on Keras. Training slows down mid epoch and ETA climbs up

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, nvidia

I am trying to train c3d on keras (v2.2.0)

Hyper-parameters and info:

1. Batch Size - 32
2. Number of Keras workers for generator - 32 (with max_queue_size = 30)
3. Amazon EC2 p3.8xlarge machine
4. Num GPU 4
5. One Data Point numpy dimension: (90x80x80x3)[video of sequence length 90, and image dimension 80,80,3]
6. Optimizer - adam
7. Learning Rate - 8e-5

the output architecure is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1 (Conv3D)               (None, 90, 80, 80, 64)    5248
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 90, 40, 40, 64)    0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv3D)               (None, 90, 40, 40, 128)   221312
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 45, 20, 20, 128)   0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3a (Conv3D)              (None, 45, 20, 20, 256)   884992
_________________________________________________________________
conv3b (Conv3D)              (None, 45, 20, 20, 256)   1769728
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 22, 10, 10, 256)   0
_________________________________________________________________
conv4a (Conv3D)              (None, 22, 10, 10, 512)   3539456
_________________________________________________________________
conv4b (Conv3D)              (None, 22, 10, 10, 512)   7078400
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 11, 5, 5, 512)     0
_________________________________________________________________
conv5a (Conv3D)              (None, 11, 5, 5, 512)     7078400
_________________________________________________________________
conv5b (Conv3D)              (None, 11, 5, 5, 512)     7078400
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding3d_1 (ZeroPaddin (None, 11, 7, 7, 512)     0
_________________________________________________________________
pool5 (MaxPooling3D)         (None, 5, 3, 3, 512)      0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 23040)             0
_________________________________________________________________
fc6 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              94375936
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0
_________________________________________________________________
fc7 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 24582
=================================================================
Total params: 138,837,766
Trainable params: 138,837,766
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The 1st epoch starts fine but around the middle, it start slowing down extremely (ETA starts increasing instead of decreasing). The frequency of GPU firing (measured using `nvidia-smi`) slows down a lot. The CPU usage also sees an increase.

The other weird thing is that the memory usage of the 4 GPUs is not uniform. It almost looks like one GPU is being used more than the others ones and gets filled up early on:

[image: This was around the middle of the epoch]

Although it is known that c3d is hard to train, smaller models like LRCN also have similar results.

Is there any optimization that I'm missing here?

Also what's the best way to profile issues like these.

**EDIT**

Subsequent runs (after hitting `ctrl+c` to above) are even worse

```
Creating train generator with 41828 samples.
2018-08-16 22:08:17.766289: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:903] failed to allocate 7.66G (8220311552 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
   4/1307 [..............................] - ETA: 12:27:49 - loss: 2.3928 - acc: 0.1406
```

Comment: May I ask what dataset you are training on, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that on multi-gpu-model if you have increase worker ETA will increase. I think you shall limit the number of workers maybe 2 or 4 depending upon your CPU power and increase batch size four times.

Since batches are load by the CPU and if you updating weights on CPU then check its utilization which may be increasing your ETA.